# Элементы размером в 1/3 не умещаются в div

Tags: html, css

Имеется три объекта `div` размеры которых чуть меньше чем 1/3 от родительского элемента. Почему они не вмещаются в ряд?

```css
#underline {
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-style: solid;
}
    
#underline-content {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
    
#box-left, #box-center, #box-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.332%;
}
```

```html
<div id="underline">
    <div id="underline-content">
        <div id="box-left">Вова</div>
        <div id="box-center">Дима</div>
        <div id="box-right">Вася</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов как убрать отступы

1) parent (`#underline-content`) - `font-size: 0;`

2) child (`[id^=box-]`) - `font-size: XXpx`

```css
#underline {
  border-top-width: thin;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
}

#underline-content {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 0;
}

#box-left,
#box-center,
#box-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.332%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="underline">
  <div id="underline-content">
    <div id="box-left">Вова</div>
    <div id="box-center">Дима</div>
    <div id="box-right">Вася</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проще говоря, чтобы убрать промежутки между `inline` элементами нужно поставить у родительского элемента размер шрифта 0 (чтобы обнулить пробелы), а у дочернего вернуть размер шрифта обратно.

```
.parent {
    font-size: 0;
}

.child {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Только нашел такое же решение.